# Push notification on iphone from my server

Tags: iphone, push-notification

I am creating an application and i'm planning to use a notification service in it. I've a server and the application is calling this server via webservices and updating its data. But i now need to enable a notification service where the user may get the updates in my server as a notification. I am planning to use Urban Airship service, but not sure how to make it communicate with my server. Or is there any other easy way to enable notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you should follow [MonoPush](http://monopush.com) Project, it's seems very cool. You can be able to access many things via api and also you can install it on your server without any message limitation , sth.